# Global Apache Log with Many Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I have a server that runs a bunch of VirtualHosts for each of our client sites (~ 30 sites).  I've got the VHosts configured so that each site has its own log, which is stored in `<public>/../log/access.log`, and similarly for an error log.

I would like to create a server-wide log of some basic information from every request - specifically time, status code, and virtual host.  Preferably, I would like to store this information in one file, rather than parsing each of the separate access logs.

Is there a way to tell Apache to follow one `CustomLog` in addition to all the ones in the actual VHost files?

Answer (score 0):

You can [pipe the logs from CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#piped). You can then use `tee`, for instance, to send them to different destinations (possibly processing them beforehand). There's an [example at fnal.gov](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/products/apache/syslog_logs_notes.html):

```
ErrorLog  "|/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/www/error.log  | /usr/bin/logger -thttpd -plocal6.err"
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/www/access.log | /usr/bin/logger -thttpd -plocal6.notice" extended_ncsa
```